# excel advanced filter keep rows with matching column a and column b

Tags: excel, vba, filter, advanced-filter

Is there a way to easily use the advanced filter to keep rows with column A == column B?

[Example of what data and current filter looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCGJ9.png)

From that, I would expect to get rows with

```
Event_Name == (First, Second, Final)
```

and rows where

```
Time_A == Time_B.
```

However, I get this,

[The output from that data and filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL3ZL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a column with `=A13=B13` which returns a Boolean and then filter for "TRUE"?

Comment: In the criteria? If so that didn't work. The TRUE in column K is set to =A6=B6

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what you are asking, in that case. From your title, it sounds like you want to filter out rows in which A does not equal B.

Comment: Yes, I want to filter out rows in which A does not equal B, while still keeping any rows that have an Event_Name equal to First, Second or Final. I think I might have misunderstood what you were trying to suggest at first. I can add a column as you suggested, however I run into a problem when I try doing this with a macro. (I need to be able to do this for multiple data sets of varying length from hundreds to a couple thousand lines.)The column ends up adding extra rows to the end of my data with the value of TRUE. Thus giving me a ton of essentially "blank" rows when I filter for TRUE.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the clarification! If you want help on a macro then you need to post what you have so far along with whatever errors you are encountering. Alternatively, a formula along the lines of `=IF(AND(A13=B13, A13<>""), "True", "False")` will return "True" when the two cells are the same and the cells are not blank. Then you can just filter for "True"